# When citing information from a source do I need multiple citations for multiple ideas or sentences

Tags: citations

I am doing the works cited part of my paper and am trying to avoid plagiarism.  I have used information which is not common knowledge in my paper so I must use citations because i have put it into my own words.  Do I have to use multiple inline citations for separate sentences or ideas even when they are from the same source? Or should I just use the citation after all the info I have referenced from that source?

Comment: This belongs to http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions or writing.SE.

Comment: I've asked the mods on Writers if they'd like this question there. If so, it will be migrated automatically. Unfortunately, we don't really deal with citations here.

Comment: This is not a question of language usage but of academic practice, which varies between disciplines.

Comment: Is this an academic paper?

Answer (score 2):

This applies within the Harvard Referencing system. You may need to check which referencing system you should be working to.

If the points taken from source have been separated by other points that are not from source, then yes, you need to recite a reference for each point. If this is the case you may want to consider revising your work so that all the points taken from source are together. This avoids this dilemma completely and means you only have to state the source once.

the thing to remember is to make sure everything said by another person is accredited to them, but no more than what they said.

**"In your paper, every time you summarise, paraphrase or quote from a source you need to provide an in-text citation.... 
In any one paragraph, if you cite an author or authors more than once in the narrative (i.e. the author’s name does not appear in parentheses), include the family name/s and year the first time. In subsequent citations in the narrative in the same paragraph you need to cite only the family name/s, and omit the year, provided studies cannot be confused, i.e, 
According to Hopkins (2004, p. 16) little attention has been given to the way a manager might identify and … Furthermore, Hopkins argues that in some business environments …*

*When the name of the author/s and year are in parentheses in any one paragraph, the year is included in subsequent citations, i.e, 
Little attention has been given to the way a manager might identify and … (Hopkins  2004, p. 16). Furthermore, Hopkins (2004, p. 16) argues that in some business environments …*"*

Ref:
Deakin University of Australia, 2002, Referencing using the author-date (Harvard) style [online] http://deakin.edu.au/current-students/study-support/study-skills/handouts/authordate-harvard.php (accessed 16th October 2012)